# Building Quic protocol on ns-3

Tags: github, ns-3, quic

I am new to using ns-3. I want to test a certain self-contained implementation of the quic protocol available on github. How can I integrate the code with ns-3 for testing under different conditions?

Comment: If there's a NS-3 QUIC implementation you can use that; else, you will have to write it yourself

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say given that you haven't linked the implementation, but if it's something standard like [this implementation](https://github.com/signetlabdei/quic), then just follow the instructions in the README.

The steps essentially amount to adding the TCP implementation to `./ns-3-dev/src`, and then telling waf about the existence of those files by adding them to the corresponding wscript file.